# replace pattern inside a line from pattern at the beginning

Tags: text-processing

Trying to replace a pattern inside text lines with a pattern found at the very beginning of the same line.

Having some text:

```
number4456 reports a high level of error
number3458 taking a proper error warning
number9273 is not an error prone software
```

Desired output:

```
reports a high level of error_number4456
taking a proper error_number3458 warning
is not an error_number9273 prone software
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `sed`:

```
LC_ALL=C sed -e 's/^\([^ ]*\) \(.* error\)/\2_\1/' <file
```

assuming that there's only one `error` occurs in a line.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{a = "";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /error/)a = a$i"_"$1" ";else a = a$i" "}print a}' yourfile
```